# How to query differences in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am facing some problem with querying table with Oracle SQL. I have been trying joins but without success.

Table contains serverid, softid, domainid. Structure of records is as fallows: 
There can be multiple domains on the same servers which might have installed the same soft.

So for domain A and B, C, D ... we can have same serverid and softid. But there might be situation where there will be new soft instilled on domain A on servers on which domian B, C, D ... is also present.

What I would like to achieve is to have query which would show me which softid is installed on the domain A and is not on the domain B, C, D ... etc.

Table would look like this:

```
DomainId = 4992  SoftId = 4823 ServerId = 4774 
DomainId = 4992  SoftId = 4824 ServerId = 4774 
DomainId = 4992  SoftId = 4823 ServerId = 4775 
DomainId = 4992  SoftId = 4824 ServerId = 4775 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4825 ServerId = 4774 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4824 ServerId = 4774 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4823 ServerId = 4774 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4825 ServerId = 4775 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4824 ServerId = 4775 
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4823 ServerId = 4775
```

I would like to obtain such result:

```
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4825 ServerId = 4774
DomainId = 4993  SoftId = 4825 ServerId = 4775
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Consistent terminology would make everything easier for all of us. You say domain A and B, C, D, but your sample data only has DomainId = 4993. Sample data should probably need several, different DomainId values. And adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Probably some variation of NOT EXISTS based on same SoftId, but different DomainId.

Comment: But wouldn't `SoftId, count(Distinct DomainId)  From Table group by SoftId having count(distinct DomainId) = 1` be enough? That can be CTE I guess and will give you which software was installed on only 1 Domain ... then just join it with your table and you'll get what you want

Comment: Do you need information of the software installed in **exactly one domain** on the server (that means it is not installed on any other domain), or information on which domain on the same server some software is missing (that means it can be installed on domains A,B, and C, but missing on D)?

Comment: @Veljko89 - Big thx. I used your suggested CTE and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out @pazzdzioh